# question about cluster points of a set of cluster points

Tags: general-topology

Let A be a set in a metric space X. A′ is the set of cluster points of A. Is it A′′ ⊆ A′ ? I think it is not. But I can not give a counterexample or proof. Could someone give me a clue? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: Yes, it is always the case that $A''\subseteq A'$. If $x\in A''$, then every open nbhd $U$ of $x$ contains some point $y\in A'$. But then $U$ is an open nbhd of $y$, so it must contain ... what?

Comment: I am sorry but I still don't get it... Could you explain that further?

Comment: @ltlltl2006: What do you have to show in order to prove that a point $y$ is a cluster point of $A$?

Comment: I guess I need to show that there is a sequence yn such that yn is not equal to y0 for all n and yn --> y0, or the equivalent definition that the intersection of U and (A'-{y}) is not empty.

Comment: @ltlltl2006: Definitely use the latter form; it’s exactly what I had in mind when I wrote the hint. You want to show that if $x\in A''$, then $x\in A'$. That means that you want to show that every open nbhd of $x$ contains a point of $A\setminus\{x\}$. Let $U$ be an open nbhd of $x$; you know that $U$ contains a point $y\in A'\setminus\{x\}$. Now use the facts that $U\setminus\{x\}$ is an open nbhd of $y$, and $y\in A'$: what must every open nbhd of $y$ contain?